# Get the hour of the calling from Android CallLog

Tags: android, call, android-contentprovider

Hey, I want to get the hour of the calling from the Android CallLog. It is, the exactly hour that the user start the calling and if possible when he finishes the calling. Someone knows how to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is complete solution (though not tested) - just scheme:

```
public void logCallLog(String number)
{
    long dialed;
    String columns[]=new String[] {
            CallLog.Calls._ID, 
            CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, 
            CallLog.Calls.DATE, 
            CallLog.Calls.DURATION, 
            CallLog.Calls.TYPE};
    String args[]=new String[1];
    args[0]=number;
    Cursor c;
    c = this.managedQuery(Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls"),
            columns, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER+"=?", args, "Calls._ID DESC"); //last record first
    while (c.moveToNext())
    {
        dialed=c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE));
        Log.i("CallLog", "Call to number: "+number+", registered at: "+new Date(dialed).toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Focused on the original question, this is a solution, based on @barmaley's:

```
public void logCallLog(String number)
{
    long dialed;
    String columns[]=new String[] {
            CallLog.Calls._ID, 
            CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, 
            CallLog.Calls.DATE, 
            CallLog.Calls.DURATION, 
            CallLog.Calls.TYPE};
    String args[]=new String[1];
    args[0]=number;
    Cursor c;
    c = this.managedQuery(Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls"), columns, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER+"=?", args, "Calls._ID DESC"); //last record first
    while (c.moveToNext())
    {
        int duration = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));// for duration in seconds            
        dialed=c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE));
        GregorianCalendar callStart = new GregorianCalendar();
        callStart.setTimeInMillis(dialed);
        int hstart = callStart.get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        //using callStart and duration you can calculate the end hour:
        dialed += duration+1000;
        GregorianCalendar callEnd = new GregorianCalendar();
        callEnd.setTimeInMillis(dialed);
        int hend = callEnd.get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        Log.i("CallLog", String.format("Start:%d End:%d", hstart, hend));
    }
}
```